# Angular multiple controller-html pairs to change a page

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am creating a web page that has three different sections.

The top section is for a navigation bar.
And two other sections each are for a status and for a contents.

I want to resue the status section with different contents, each of which has a different controller. The status section can reflect the changes in the contents sections, each of which has its own URL.

I originally thought about using $emit, $on or $broadcast, but since there can be lots of status changes to be reflected, I am worried about the performance of the application.

If I simply use one section to have both status and contents, I would have to write the same code for the status page for every contents.

What would be the best way to implement such page?

Answer (score 0):

The `$route` service is all you want.

You even have a live demo in the official documentation:

[$route documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: I am already using the $routeParameter for each of my contents page to have a URL. Is there any functionality in the $route service that might help solve my issue?